# How to put the application to backgound (onPause() state)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I created an alert dialog when back key is pressed to ask the user if he need the application to be putted into background or to exit

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Keep ON", new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            onPause();
        }

    });
    dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Exit", new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            onDestroy();
        }

    });
    dialogBuilder.setMessage("Do you want to keep the activity running on background");
    AlertDialog Dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    Dialog.show();
}
```

but calling onPause() and onDestroy() doesn't work

there is any solution that satisfy my goal please....

Comment: Please don't do this.  It is not the Android way.  There is no need to "exit" the app (do you "exit" a web page?).  Just let the back key do what it does and what users expect the normal behaviour to be.

Comment: If you still wants your app to run on background then use Service for that purpose. Or just press home button to let it go on background!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You definitely should not be calling `onPause` and `onDestroy` manually :) This is something Android does, not you.

Also, I would say such kind of dialogs is really bad user experience. Android users are well educated to know what they are doing when pressing 'back' button.

Anyways, if this dialog is really important to you, here is the thing:

- To "destroy" the app - call `finish()` in your onClick listener

  ```
  dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Exit", new OnClickListener(){
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          finish();
      }

  });
  ```
- With "backgrounding" things are a bit trickier. You need to send an intent to launch home activity:

  ```
  dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Keep ON", new OnClickListener(){
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
          intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
          startActivity(intent);
      }
  });
  ```

Also if you have your own handling of "back" button press, I would not call `super.onBackPressed()` since it will finish your activity - this is a default behaviour

Comment: i'd give two votes if possible :) 1 for the the platform and 1 for UX. good job.